# How to read this logs text file in C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

How to read this log.txt text file into my program in to a struct? ( C++ )
////////////////////////logs.txt////////////////////////////

```
Port4000.txt:M:r:10

Port4001.txt:M:w:1

Port4002.txt:M:w:9

Port4003.txt:J:x:1
```

***Represent:***

Port40xx.txt represent port number
:
M represent user
:
r represent action
:
10 represent threshold

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
struct Pair
{

 char user;

char action;

}

int main()
{

  Pair pairs;

  ifstream infile;

  char portnumber[20];


  infile.open("logs.txt",ios::in); // `open the log text file `


  infile.getline(portnumber,20,':'); //`Reading the portnumber of the user and action
`

 infile >> pairs.user >> pairs.action >> threshold;

 //`THE PROBLEM IS HOW TO read the user, action, threshold whenever it meets ":" symbol?`

infile.close();

return 0;

}
```

Please let me know if there is any way for reading char data type until it meets ":" symbol and start to read another char data type. Thank you :)

Comment: "Port40xx.txt represent port number" - that's a weird number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep doing what you did for "portnumber":

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c50d424b6ac703b7)</kbd>**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Pair {
    char user;
    char action;
};

int main()
{

    std::ifstream infile;

    infile.open("logs.txt", std::ios::in); // `open the log text file `

    std::string portnumber, user, action, threshold;
    if (getline(infile, portnumber, ':')
            && getline(infile, user, ':') && user.size() == 1
            && getline(infile, action, ':') && action.size() == 1
            && getline(infile, threshold, '\n'))
    {
        Pair pair { user[0], action[0] };

    }
}
```

Note the use of `std::getline` is safer (and more convenient) than `std::istream::getline`